Update Excel cell values using links indirectly
I have my master data sheet where I have data from other multiple data files. What I would like to do is to call this data automatically, like the links do. However, these data files don't have always the same name, so what I want is to type the file name in a cell and call the data using CONCAT with the filename and the range and INDIRECT formula. However, Excel doesn't recognize this as a link, so the data is not updated when I open my master sheet. If I have the data files opened, the values are shown in the master sheet, but I don't want to open every data file.
Is there a way to get this without using VBA?
Thanks!!

I typed in search box excel reference closed workbook dynamic and got a lot of answers, but not too promising ones.

Look into combining data from a folder using Power Query. You could filter out the name of your master workbook before combining the other files.
